# Loading multiple partial for vuejs component

Tags: javascript, mvvm, vue.js

Can you load a partial for a vuejs component from within that component's file if the component file is being loaded/used via browserify and require()?

I have a view which uses a common component...but the way to display that component is specific to this one view (a list of all of the 'users' in a system).

user.js:

```
module.exports = {
    template: '<partial name="users-view-user"></partial>',
}
```

users-view.js:

```
module.exports = {
    template: require('users.template.html'),

    components: {
        'user': require('../components/user')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`./components/user.js:`

```
module.exports = {
    template: '<partial name="users-view-user"></partial>',

    partials: {
        'users-view-user': 'boom'
    }
}
```

`./users-view.js:`

```
module.exports = {
    template: require('users.template.html'),

    components: {
        'user': require('../components/user')
    }
}
```

I've also been told there is a way to have the partial used be a variable, so user.js's template could be something like `<partial name="{{ something-here }}"></partial>` which is how I'll actually end up needing to use it. Haven't figured this out yet.